# Making array into multidimensional array with same key => value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this

```
$arr = ['Hello', 'World'];
```

What I am trying to achieve is

```
$arr [
   'Hello' => 'Hello',
   'World' => 'World'
]
```

Is there a array method to achieve this or should I run a foreach loop and do it manually? I am just thinking if there is a more elegant way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `array_combine` for this

```
$new = array_combine($arr, $arr);
print_r($new);
```